# How to insert into a collection dynamically?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'd like to know if there is a way to insert into mongo db without going through the usual `db.mycollection.insert` but instead something like :

`db.insert({collection: 'mycollection', document: ...})`

Or even a more liberal approach to query such as :
`db.query(...)`

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: `db.getCollection(your_dynamic_name).insertOne(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define variables and use them in different ways to execute your queries (CRUD operations), in `mongosh` or the `mongo` shell.

Some examples:

```
var docs = [ { name: "John", city: "New York" }, { name: "Kim", city: "Oslo" } ]
var usersColl = "users"
var insertCmd = {
   insert: usersColl,
   documents: docs
}
```

Insert Documents (using any way suitable to you):

```
db.runCommand(insertCmd)
db.getCollection(usersColl).insertMany(docs);
```

Query:

```
db.getCollection(usersColl).find()
```

Assign collection to a variable and apply query methods on it:

```
var dbColl = db.getCollection(usersColl)
dbColl.insertOne({ name: "Jane", city: "Hamburg" })
dbColl.find()
```

**References:**

- [mongosh Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/)
- [Database
  Commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/)

Comment: That is perfect, run command is exactly what I was looking for